# django admin panel healthcheck

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to create a healthcheck endpoint for my django admin panel.
I want to register it via `admin.site.register_view` (I am using the [adminplus package](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus)) but I can't figure out how to made it accessible to the public, without the need to authenticate first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up overriding `def has_permission(self, request)` in subclass of `AdminPlusMixin`:

```
from adminplus.sites import AdminPlusMixin


class MyAdmin(AdminPlusMixin, AdminSite):

    def has_permission(self, request):
        if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'admin-healthcheck':
            return True
        return super().has_permission(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that package is outdated, instead you could do something like the following:

Created a proxy model in **models.py** such as:

```
class Proxy(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)

    def str(self):
        return "<Label: id: %d>" % self.id

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        verbose_name_plural = 'proxies'
        db_table = 'proxy'
        ordering = ('id',)
```

Which is just a **mysql view** that a created from am existing table

```
 create view proxy
    as select id
    from samples
    LIMIT 10;
```

And finally in **admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Proxy)
class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'label_view.html'
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
      ...
        return render(request, "label_view.html", context)
```

This way it will show in the admin panel, inside the app you're working on.

Probably what you have is a function in your views.py, in this case you should replace that function content where the "..." are in the LabelAdmin class.